# Must I check the kashrut certificate every time I visit a bakery or restaurant?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, restaurant, chazaka

Say I visit a bakery, restaurant, jail, hospital, or nursing home.  And say I already know that the food there is kosher.  Must I still check the kashrut certificate every time I visit?

(Gershon Gold, thank you for [inspiring](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/in-a-bulk-food-store-must-i-ask-to-see-the-original-label-every-time-i-return-a#comment24177_13776) this question.)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8949.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally (at least here in Israel) they have it on display so generally I would think just noticing that it is still there and not expired should be OK.

EDIT: In many towns in Israel the certificates change color every quarter, so you can often tell if it is up to date just by the fact that it is the correct color

Answer (score 2):

Every certificate I have ever seen has a date on it.  You only need to check the teudah Kashrut(Kosher certificate) once per date range.

Comment: Do you have a source? I think it would be reasonable to argue that either the assumption that the food is permissible generally applies, regardless of how far into the date range you are, or that the assumption never holds so you need to check on each visit.

Answer (score 2):

You should check that the Kashrus certificate is available and not expired, each time you go.

Many of the kashrus agencies now have signature stamps AND holographic stickers on them to ensure that it's not a photocopy.

For example, see information about [Badatz Beit Yosef](http://www.jerusalemkoshernews.com/2009/10/a-look-at-badatz-beit-yosef/) with a picture of one of their [teudot kashrut](http://www.jerusalemkoshernews.com/wp-content/uploads/aldo-on-jaffa-beit-yosef-certiciate2.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

The certificate can be revoked without your knowledge at any time, so I would say you should check it each time, and make sure the the dates is still good.

Comment: If it's revoked, can't the restaurant still have a photocopy of the old one posted? How does it help to check?

Comment: Theoretically I suppose they can, but legally they cannot.

Comment: @andrewmh20: +1. Still, I'm curious. What law says they cannot post a photocopy of the revoked certificate?

Comment: As far as I am aware, the kashrut companies always _own_ the certificate, and are licensing it to be posted in an establishment they approve of, _with the condition_ that it must be removed if the kashrut company says so.